# grep anomaly in filtering .csv

Tags: bash, csv, grep

I have an an odd occurrence when attempting to filter rows from a .csv file:

I have two .csvs, one containing a large amount of data, another containing identifiers (the name in the first column of the main .csv) of rows to remove from the first file.

The main file looks like:

```
scaffold_1234_ref00001_1234,0,1,NA,0.8... 
scaffold_1235_ref00002_12345,1,0.3,NA,1...
```

The second looks like:

```
scaffold_1234_ref0001_1234
scaffold_1234_ref_002_1234
```

I've been using `grep -v -f filter.csv data_to_filter.csv > filtered.csv` which does appear to produce an output file missing the necessary rows, however there are more missing than anticipated in the output file.

The initial data contains 1,142,936 rows, I'm attempting to remove 122,788, yet 123,036 are deleted in the output file (248 too many!).

I've checked for duplications in the main data using `awk -F, 'a[$1]++{print $1}' data_to_filter.csv` but this shows up no duplications.

Any ideas? I'm kinda new to this!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the data, but it's likely that some of your identifiers are either substrings of other identifiers (e.g., "foo" would match "foo", "foobar" and "somefoo"), or your some of your column data contains references to identifiers in other columns. Maybe remove the `-v` and inspect the results to see exactly which lines are matching?

Comment: Can you edit the second file? Looks like it would benefit from being transformed with `sed 's/.*/^&,'` (adding the "start of a line" `^` anchor at the start of each pattern and the CSV separator at their end) in order to avoid what larsks suspects

Comment: In regard with my previous comment : the file once transformed should probably not be considered a CSV anymore as the trailing comma would be considered a separator rather than part of the data. Avoiding that would require enclosing the cells in quotes, but the lines of the file then wouldn't be the desired grep patterns anymore.

Comment: As a general matter, when trying to match against specific fields on each line it is simpler and more reliable to use a tool that is aware of the field boundaries. `grep` is not. A good list of tools is here: [Structured Text Tools: Other tools](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#other-tools). There are several on the list that directly support the type of join you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

With your grep command `grep -v -f filter.csv data_to_filter.csv` you're doing a partial regexp match across each line of data so this:

```
scaffold_1234_ref0001_1234
```

would match

```
scaffold_1234_ref0001_1234567
fooscaffold_1234_ref0001_1234
```

and many more values in the first field AND it would match similar strings anywhere else on each line. It would also use any RE metacharacters as such so `.` would mean `any character`, etc. Either or both of those could explain why it's removing more lines than expected. Do this exact string match on the full text of the specific target field instead:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{filter[$0];next} !($1 in filter)' filter.csv data_to_filter.csv
```

Comment: I just tried that as 'awk -F, 'NR==FNR{filter[$0];next} !($1 in filter)' filter.csv data_to_filter.csv > test.txt' but the output file seems to be exactly the same as data_to_filter.csv?
Could it be a formatting issue with the filter.csv?

Comment: Yes, you could have white space in it and/or `\r`s at the end of each line. Try running `dos2unix` on it then try again.

Comment: tried dos2unix - command still just returning the entire data_to_filter.csv file. Most perplexing!

Comment: Try it with small files of a couple of lines each.

Comment: OK but now that your input is just a couple of lines you can easily figure out what's causing the problem, right?